# metrics from the postgres_exporter

Tags: prometheus-postgres-exporter

I am working on postgres monitoring by referring to [page](https://docs.sysdig.com/en/docs/sysdig-monitor/monitoring-integrations/application-integrations/postgresql/), and my postgres_exporter version is v0.8.0, and found some metrics missing, for example:

- pg_stat_user_tables_n_tup_hot_upd
- pg_stat_user_tables_idx_scan
- pg_stat_user_tables_seq_scan

Is there anyone who uses these metrics? and what is the postgres_exporter version?
Thank you.